# Configure primary DNS Setting via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a script to configure the primary DNS server setting.

We have mixed OSes such as 2021R2 ,2016 ,2019 and domain-joined and/or workgroup.

Mostly,  We have 2 NICs on Windows Machine.

My question is: I want to change Only the primary DNS address on machine. I am trying a script like the one below. But I haven't had any luck.

script :

```
$wmi = Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername localhost | where { $_.IPEnabled -eq "TRUE" -and $_.DNSServerSearchOrder -ne $null }
$dns1 = "101.61.241.311"
$wmi.SetDNSServerSearchOrder("$dns1")
```

script output :

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
ReturnValue      : 70
PSComputerName   :
```

Sample interface Output:

```
PSComputerName               : server01
DHCPLeaseExpires             : 
Index                        : 10
Description                  : vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter
DHCPEnabled                  : False
DHCPLeaseObtained            : 
DHCPServer                   : 
DNSDomain                    : 
DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder   : {contoso.local}
DNSEnabledForWINSResolution  : False
DNSHostName                  : server01
DNSServerSearchOrder         : {192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2}
DomainDNSRegistrationEnabled : False
FullDNSRegistrationEnabled   : True
IPAddress                    : {192.168.0.8, fe80::cc2f:c777:11f4:4bbb}
IPConnectionMetric           : 5
IPEnabled                    : True
IPFilterSecurityEnabled      : False
WINSEnableLMHostsLookup      : True
```

Comment: DNS Server is 1 setting for entire list, not 1 setting for each item in the list. So you can't change just 1, but you can get the current list, test and figure out what needs to change, build the new list (even if secondary IP will be the same), and use that array to "Set" the setting.

Answer (score 0):

i would go with netsh... for example:

```
Netsh interface ipv4 set dns name=Ethernet static 101.61.241.311 primary
```

if you know the mac address or IP you can also filter for them to set the dns.

Comment: btw be very careful if you change DNS settings on a domain controller...

Answer (score 0):

This may be easier to do with the networking commands. Here's how to set only the primary dns server:

```
# Get your adapter's interface id
$interface = Get-NetIPInterface | 
  Where { $_.ConnectionState -eq 'Connected' -and $_.InterfaceAlias -notlike 'Loopback*' }

# Check the current DNS Server(s) on that interface:
$DNSCurrent = $interface | Get-DnsClientServerAddress

# fill in new dns server info:
$dns1 = '101.61.241.311'
$dns2 = $DNSCurrent.ServerAddresses[0]  # make current primary server secondary
$dns3 = $DNSCurrent.ServerAddresses[1]  # optional third


# if the first address is wrong, then set it
if ($DNSCurrent.ServerAddresses[0] -NE $dns1) {
  $interface | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses $dns1,$dns2,$dns3
}
```